# Detecting crop/printer marks in a PDF document using iTextSharp (C#)

Tags: c#, pdf, printing, itext, crop

I’m currently trying to check if there are crop/printer marks present in a PDF document. I tried to search for a solution on StackOverflow and Google, but with no results. The so called ‘trim box’ or ‘crop box’ are not the same as the crop/printer marks.

One thing that I tried and remembered is using the ‘pdfReader.GetPdfObject(i)’ method to search for a property or setting that was relevant to the crop/printer marks, but I could not find what I was looking for. To give you a better explanation I added an example below of how the "optimal" solution would look like:

```
 public bool HasCropMarks(PdfReader pdfReader)
    {
        var cropMarks = pdfReader.GetCropMarks();
        return cropMarks == null;
    }
```

Does anyone has experience with getting crop/printer marks information out of a PDF document and if so, do you mind to share your information?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A problem is that crop marks can be added to a PDF as regular content and, therefore, be indistinguishable from regular content.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I was already headed towards that direction, but now I know it for sure. Is there there a possibility to receive the regular content of a PDF document? I'm still searching for this answer, but may be you can push me towards the right direction?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18216435/finding-a-line-in-an-image-file for more information on crop/trim/bleed boxes.

Comment: @Gilian *Is there there a possibility to receive the regular content of a PDF document?* - you have tagged your question iTextSharp. That library has high level support for extracting text and bitmap images (parser namespace) and low level support for extracting any kind of content.